# How to convert CodeSoft .lab files to parsable plain text?

Tags: printing, printer, conversion, label, label-printer

I have ~1000 sticker label `.lab` files. I would need to convert these to some plain text format so that the contents of the files could be parsed with Python.

CodeSoft has an option to choose from a huge list of printers and print the results to a file. I've tried printing with tons of different printer makers/models, but always after printing, the `.txt` file gets generated just fine, but it's never in format where it would have the field values as just plaintext ascii.

I've also tried adding a `Generic / Text Only` printer with the port set as `FILE` in Windows settings, but after printing with that some of the text from the labels is cut off in the printed `.txt` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by printing the `.lab` files to `.pdf`s from Codesoft, and then converting the `.pdf`s to `.txt` files using [`pdftotext`](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html).